# max() function can't find correct value. php

Tags: php, arrays, max

I'm trying to get the max value in the array.
But using max() for the entire array it can't find the highest value:

[image]

The return Key is 2, which is not the correct key, obviously the highest value is in array(3).
Please help me to find my mistake.
Here bellow is my code:

```
<?php
$hex_splited = [
        ['00','00','00'], 
        ['10', '11', '10'], 
        ['F0', '1A', 'C3'],
        ['0F', 'FE', 'F4'],
       ];
$arr_rgb = [];
$count2 = count($hex_splited);
for ($i=0; $i < $count2; $i++) { 
    $inn_count = count($hex_splited[$i]);
    for ($j=0; $j < $inn_count; $j++) { 
            $val = hexdec($hex_splited[$i][$j]);
            $arr_rgb[$i][$j] = $val;
    }
}
$max = max($arr_rgb);
var_dump($max);
$key = array_search($max, $arr_rgb);
echo "<pre>";
echo "array key is: " . $key;
echo "</pre>";

    echo "<table border='1'>";
for ($m=0; $m < $count2; $m++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($k=0; $k < $inn_count; $k++) { 
        echo "<td>";
        echo $arr_rgb[$m][$k];
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I think the mistake lies in the assumption that max will work as you expect it to on 2d arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `max()` doesn't always behave as you would expect when using multidimensional arrays.

This code does the processing in two stages, first finds the max value.  As this is only a 2 dimensional simple array, you can use...

```
$max = max(array_map("max", $hex_splited));
```

This applies max to each of the sub arrays and then gets the max of those values.

So in your case, this will be `'FE'`.  Then as part of the loop which converts the data to decimal, it compares the original value with the max already found and stores the key...

```
$key = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < $count2; $i++) {
    $inn_count = count($hex_splited[$i]);
    for ($j=0; $j < $inn_count; $j++) {
        $val = hexdec($hex_splited[$i][$j]);
        $arr_rgb[$i][$j] = $val;
        // Check if found the max value
        if ( $max == $hex_splited[$i][$j] ) {
            $key = $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From here, how I can get the key of the sub array

Comment: That should be the `$key = $i;` part.

Comment: My mistake, i didn't delete the old code. Thank you very much!